# Is there any way to add SRS support to cPanel to fix forwarders and SPF records?

Tags: email, spf

[According to OpenSPF](http://www.openspf.org/SRS),

> SPF "breaks" email forwarding. SRS is a way to fix it.

This is true on one of the cPanel/WHM servers I manage. A customer has a forwarder set up and she is complaining that emails sent to that email address `@herdomain.com` bounce. Investigating the logs, I see that my server tries to forward the emails as she has requested, and her other provider is rejecting the email because my server isn't allowed by SPF. Since we have no idea who will be sending her email, it's not feasible to have me in the SPF record for all her senders' domains, clearly.

It seems like [SRS: Sender Rewriting Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme) is the way to go. is there any official support for SRS from cPanel? If not, can it be added manually via the command line / Exm Configuration Editor?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @HopelessN00b This question is **on topic** because it is about managing the hardware or software of servers while working as a sysadmin for a service provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SRS can not be enabled from cPanel yet. You need to enable SRS manually from exim configuration file. The below article will guide you through the steps to enable SRS in cPanel version 11.28:

http://mg.iceni.pl/archives/11

Comment: Hmmm, thanks. If I just apply that patch cPanel will surely overwrite it but maybe there is a way to apply those changes within the supported Exim Configuration Editor... Do you have experience with this by any chance?